# Multiple inheritance in Swift

Tags: swift, multiple-inheritance

So I have a problem where I get shown the error

> multiple inheritance from classes UIViewController and UIFont

and being new to programming, I don't really understand what is wrong. So what does this error mean? Can't I add more protocols to the class? This is how my code looks

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

 var items:[String] = []

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIFont {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]        
        return cell
    }
    func fontWithSize(fontSize: 130) -> UIFont {
        return fontSize
    }



    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if var storeditems: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("items") {
            items = []
            for var i = 0; i<storeditems?.count; ++i {
                items.append(storeditems?[i] as NSString)
            }

            func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

                if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
                    items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(items, forKey: "items")
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View Controller 2

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

        items.append(textField.text)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(items, forKey: "items")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift and Objective-C only support single inheritance. They do support multiple protocols. Extension is principally achieved via composition.

`UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` are protocols.

`UIFont` is not a protocol, it is a class.

Comment: I tried working that, but that doesn't work. It still says multiple inheritance from classes. What i am actually trying to do is add another protocol named UIFont to edit the font style.

Comment: There is not protocol named `UIFont`, that is a class. Why do you thing you need to include it as a protocol?

Comment: Yeah my bad, UIFont is a class, i am pretty new to programming let alone OOPs. Having a hard time finding my way through this

Comment: You write "OOPs", I write "Oops" :-;

Comment: Actually, there are 2 types of inheritance: inheritance of interface and implementation. So, both Swift and Objective-C do support inheritance :)

Comment: Also currently Swift supports default implementation of protocols, so basically it's inheritance of implementation.